# забита оперативная память

Tags: windows, windows-10

чем может быть занято столько оперативы? на борту 8гб.
прогонял оперативку через стандартный тест винды - ошибок нет.
если полностью вырубить хром, торрент и другие жрущие программы - загрузка памяти падает лишь до 40-50%
и может есть программы для более точного отображения загрузки ресурсов по каждому процессу?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

новые скрины

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Sysinternals Utilities](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/)

Comment: 4Гиг -10-ка ест

Comment: странно, люди в интернетиках пишут, что обычно 10ка жрет 1-2гб.

Comment: Home Edition занимает 1-2 гига. Профессиональная может быть и побольше. Запустите антивирус, может кто-то заполз.

Comment: Скриншот вкладки `Подробности` предоставьте, предварительно отсортеруйте по памяти, там и увидем, что у вас жрёт так много памяти.

Comment: Выньте половину памяти из компа - потребление памяти уменьшится. Но иногда будет подтормаживать. Да, вот так... Сейчас все приложения разменивают память на производительность. Пока есть память - они её жрут. И лишь когда её не хватает, начинают освобождать. А если её изначально мало, то и жрать не будут. Вопрос, конечно, в том, почему это не отображается в Диспетчере задач?

Comment: залил новые скрины. антивирус ничего не нашел. антималварь тоже ничего подозрительного не увидел

Comment: На борту у Вас 8ГБ, а ОС 64бит? или 32бит?

Comment: Скриншот свойств компьютера, такое ощущение, будто у вас 32-ух разрядная винда и на борту всего 4 гб ОЗУ.

Comment: залил скрин. ессесна х64 и 8гб

Comment: Торрент-клиент забирает память под раздаваемые файлы, чтобы не дёргать жёсткий диск. MsMpEng — это встроенный в Windows антивирус. Ну а хром — это хром, из-за своей многопроцесности он спокойно соревнуется с Firefox по потреблению памяти.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Таких метрик как "память" и "загрузка памяти" нет.

OS не "выделяет физическую память" напрямую процессу. Вместо этого процессу выделяется память в виртульном адресном пространстве, и OS по ходу работы решает, какую часть этой памяти стоит отобразить в физическую память, какую-в своп, какую можно расшарить с другими процессами, а какую - оставить именно этому процессу.

С точки зрения процесса - ему выделено какой-то памяти размером в Commit Size.

Та метрика, которую вы смотрите на последнем скрине - "Память (а" - это Active Private Working Set) - физическая память, которая не разделяется этим процессом с другими, за вычетом памяти Suspended UWP приложений. Она не учитывает разделяемую между процессами память, память под драйвера, память по саму систему и много чего еще.

К сожалению, посчитать общее потребление памяти, просто сложив какой-то показатель по процессам, не получится.

Вот конкретный пример. Есть процессы A B С, каждый из которых получил по 1Mb приватной памяти. Общего между ABC по 1Mb, между BC - 2Mb.  Вы получите картину:

```
A - 1 Mb private, 1 Mb shared, 
B - 1 Mb private, 3 Mb shared
C - 1 Mb private, 3 Mb shared
```

Task Manager покажет в выбранной вами колонке 1+1+1=3, реально используется 6, при этом ни одно сложение 6 не дает.